# CSS List Styling, First Element Only

Tags: css

I have a list that's nested, as follows:

*List

- List item (Styled li)
- List item

  *List

  - List item
  - List item
- List item
- List item

The entire UL is wrapped in a DIV with the ID "menu", and each list element also contains a link I am trying to style.

I have a CSS rule like this:

```
#menu > ul > li > a::first-letter {
    font-size: 105%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I ONLY want this rule to apply to the links in the first level of LI elements, not the list elements in the second, nested, list.

Any info is much appreciated.

EDIT

My code works, except it also changes the elements inside the nested lists, when I only want it to apply to the first level only.

Comment: It works. If not, please create a fiddle.

Comment: I tried and your CSS code is working. We will need to see your full code.

Comment: Hei! 
Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/ywoqjoo1/ :) Hope this helps!

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: My code works, except it also changes the elements inside the nested lists, when I only want it to apply to the first level only.

Comment: Sorry, the issue was a cached css file

Answer (score 2):

You can only select the [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) of block level elements so, to select the `::first-letter` of an anchor element, which is an inline element, you will need to change its `display` property to `block` or `inline-block`.

```css
a{color:#000;display:inline-block;}
div>ul>li>a::first-letter{color:#f00;font-size:105%;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The links are block elements already. My code works, except it also changes the elements inside the nested lists, when I only want it to apply to the first level only.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was a cached css file. I flagged this question for a moderator to close it. Sorry about that.

Comment: As SO is intended to be a repository of information, a better approach would be to leave it open and accept an answer that addresses the issue as presented, which does not make mention of the `display` property.

Answer (score -1):

use first-letter class in li

```css
#menu > ul > li::first-letter {
    font-size: 105%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DEF</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GHI</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```